# Derivations: $D(f)=0 \Rightarrow f$ constant?

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives, linear-transformations

A friend of mine was supposed to proof that the derivative of a (complex) function is zero iff the function is constant. This can be proven straightforward, but I thought maybe this holds for derivations in general, so that he could prove it without using analysis.

One direction has been easy "$\Leftarrow$":
$D(1) = D(1*1) = 2D(1)$ therefore $D(1) = 0$.
Now $f$ const. $\Rightarrow D(f)=0$ follows by linearity of $D$.

But I have no idea for the other direction. Maybe it just isn't true for derivations in general.

Answer (score 3):

Take the zero derivation. It's $0$ on every function, so not only the constant ones; therefore there really is some analytic input here (I'm not saying the analytic input is necessarily huge, but it exists)

Comment: That's helpful! But would it hold of we would exclude the zero derivation? I have no experience with derivations, but my feeling is that even if the statement is totally false, the way it is false is still interesting enough to think about it (that's at least my experience with algebra).

Comment: The answer is no : consider three rings with maps $R\to A\to B$, so $B$ is an $A$-algebra, $A$ an $R$-algebra. Then take a nonzero $A$-linear derivation of $B$, and consider it as an $R$-linear derivation (so you start seeing $B$ as an $R$-algebra). Then your derivation will be zero on $A$, which doesn't necessarily consist in constants (that is, elements of $R$)

Answer (score 3):

Another point of view would be to take a concrete non-trivial example: take $C^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$, and consider the derivation $D = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. The equation $Df=0$ only means that $f$ doesn't depend on $x$, not that it is constant, e.g. for $f(x,y) = y$ we have $Df=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the operator $D$ is linear. What this means is that, for every complex *number* $\lambda$ and every differentiable function $f$, you have $D(\lambda f)=\lambda D(f)$. This doesn't apply if $\lambda$ is a non-constant function.

Comment: Isn't $D$ always an linear operator? At least that's how I understood the Wikipedia article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra).

Comment: Did you read the first sentence of my answer? It says: “Yes, the operator $D$ is linear.”

Comment: Of course I read your first sentence, I just don't understand the relation between the first and the last sentence; If $D$ is always linear, how can linearity fail if $\lambda$ (did you mean $f$?) isn't linear?

Comment: You seem to believe that $D(f)=D(f\times1)=f\times D(1)$, for an arbitrary differentiable function $f$. The last equality is way much stranger than linearity. Linearity just says that $D(\lambda f)=\lambda D(f)$ when $\lambda$ is a *number*.

Comment: Oh, of course, I totally overlooked that $D$ is $K$-linear but not a homomorphism. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the question is *meaningless* for derivations in general.

In general, a *derivation* is a linear map $D$ from an algebra $A$ to  itself such that $D(xy)=xDy+yDx$. In this generality asking whether $Dx=0$ implies $x$ iis constant is simply nonsense, since "$x$ is constant" is undefined.

Comment: In general, your algebra $A$ is over a base ring (or even field) $R$, and its "constants" are elements of $R$, so it makes sense. It is always true that an $R$-linear derivation is zero on "constants" in this sense, it is reasonable to wonder what kind of converse there could be.

Comment: @Max Huh??? Say $A$ is an algebra over $R$ and $D$ is a derivation on $A$. When we ask whether $Dx=0$ implies $x$ is constant we must be talking about $x\in A$. So now defining "$x$ is constant" to mean $x\in R$ implies that there (in general)  are no constants in $A$, since $A\cap R=\emptyset$.

Comment: When I say $x\in R$ I "obviously" mean in the image of $R$ under the structural morphism $R\to A$, e.g. the structural morphism $\mathbb R\to C^\infty(\mathbb R)$

Comment: "e.g.": I understand what the constants in $C^\infty(\Bbb R)$ are; that example doesn't help "in general".

Comment: Whenever you have an $R$-algebra $A$, you have a structural morphism $R\to A$ : it can either be part of the definition of algebra, or be defined as $r\mapsto r\cdot 1_A$. Then we may take "constants" to mean the elements in its image. Any $R$-linear derivation on $A$ will vanish on those constants

Comment: @Max You say the existence of that morphism "can be" part of the definition of "algebra".  I didn't say anything about what can or cannot be defined, I said the notion of a constant element of $A$ _is_ undefined. Whether or not it "can be" part of the definition, it _is not_ part of the definition, in any version I've seen.

Comment: @Max Just to give some evidence that I'm not simply missing the definition of "algebra": Let $A=C_0(\Bbb R)$, the space of complex-valued continuous functions on the line that vanish at infinity. Now $A$ is an algebra by the standard definitions; in fact it's a standard example of a _Banach algebra_. In this example what is that "structural morphism" you refer to?

Comment: We have a misunderstanding about the definition of algebra then, I was implicitly speaking of unital algebras (as my notation $r\mapsto r\cdot 1_A$ suggested, and as the original question also suggested, using the notation $1$). Of course if your algebra is not unital there is no structural morphism and the notion of constants doesn't make sense; but given the context (and my personal habits), I took algebra to mean unital algebra

Comment: @Max As of liaryus' answer this is all moot, since the result is false for unital algebras..

Comment: Yes I know, I also gave a trivial example as well as a recipe to cook up a bunch of nontrivial  examples. This doesn't change the fact that the question makes sense, which was my only point all along.